# Is there a general way to express how you feel?

Tags: set-phrases

For example, while I am running I feel great.
This makes me feel happy.

When doing lots of work for low wages I feel tired.

What are the common ways to express my physiological/psychological state?

Comment: Is it your policy to type the first person pronoun in small case?

Comment: @sawa. I do not think it is useful to nitpick in this circumstance.

Comment: @Flaw This kind of styling is due to sloppyness unless it is an intended style (That is why I asked). It is not something that you need advanced knowledge, nor is it a mistake. If someone is asking a question, they should ask in a neat format. That is the etiquette, at least among Japanese speaking people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 気持ちいい 'feel good'
- 爽快だ '(often after sweating, or drinking carbonated drink, etc.) feel refreshed'
- 疲れた 'got tired'
- 飽きた 'got bored'
- うんざりだ 'be sick of'

Comment: Let me add 気持ち悪い'feel sick'--Maybe it's like when you feel like throwing up?

Comment: Can we simply use psycho/physiological adjectives as an exclamation? E.g. "うれしい", "悲しい", "寂しい", "厚い", "寒い", "痛い" etc.

Comment: It's 暑い, not 厚い…

Answer (score 1):

It depends on physiological/psychological state.
「気持ちいい」- "I feel good"
「よく汗をかく」- "I worked well" ("work" = "exercise")
「楽しい」- "It's enjoy", "It's pleasure" etc.
「疲れた」- "I feel tired"
「さっぱりだ」- "I`m feeling refreshed"
etc.

Comment: Hmm, さっぱりだ sounds more like 全然/全然だめだ/全くだめだ. When you feel refreshed you'd say さっぱりした, no?

Comment: I heard "さっぱり!!!" from japanese after onsen... Of course, it has a few meanings.

Comment: 「さっぱり!!」 can mean either「爽快だ」 or 「全然だ」, but 「さっぱりだ。」cannot mean 「爽快だ」, nor can 「さっぱりした」 mean 「全然だ」.